# View LogCat from unrooted android device without computer assistance

Tags: logging

Ever since Android 4.1's new security model, all LogCat viewers I've came across require root access. Even the LogCat viewer for the IDE I'm using (AIDE) won't work.

Without rooting my device, or needing a computer to assist me, how could I view the logcat of programs I write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without root or a PC: you can't. As you noted, the behavior you're seeing is entirely intentional, and cannot be changed. If you could find a custom ROM that did not enforce these restrictions then you could feasibly install that, but if you do not want to root then I would assume this is also not an option (and I would imagine such a ROM may not exist). The only other option would be to write your own LogCat viewer within your apps, since [each app can access its own log data](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/AvZsrTdfICIJ).

Comment: Luckily I got my IDE's logcat to work. I also found that catching unchecked exceptions and printing the stacktrace allowed me to work around the need for a logcat. Although, I never thought about creating my own logcat, so thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: the link provided no longer works

Answer (score 0):

With the following command you can give the app permission to read all logs without root permissions:

```
adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

It works at least with catlog application in Samsung Galaxy S5/Android 6.0 as well as with Galaxy S7/Android 6.0.1.